# delete a record with join tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Can we delete a record from a table with the use of joins like below with out the use of IN

```
delete FROM Shippers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Orders.Shipper_ID = Shippers.Shipper_ID
where Orders.Order_ID = 3
```

Comment: Do you want to delete from *Shipper*, from *Orders* or from both?

Comment: No, you can't do `join` in Oracle in a `DELETE` clause. damn it...

Comment: no i want to delete only records from shippers where the order id is 3 in orders table

Comment: But your current example selects records with shipper id = 3 (not order id).

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.
What you can do is to use `EXISTS` clause.
like this :

```
DELETE FROM SHIPPERS S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM ORDERS O
              WHERE S.SHIPPER_ID = O.SHIPPER_ID
              AND O.ORDER_ID = 3)
```

Comment: the inner query of yours should be a join query know? I change my original query also a bit as i found its incorrect.

Comment: No, the inner query is implicitly joined with outer table. I changed the code to match your change.